# Deleting a message over imap using curl

Tags: curl, imap, gmail-imap

I am working on a project where I need to read messages in an inbox on an imap server, process it and then delete the email from the inbox.

I can successufully get the email without any issue, the problem I am having is the delete.

I can fetch the email using the following:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password"
```

This works perfectly fine for getting the email, I successfully process it without issue so now when I try and delete it I use the following:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X 'UID STORE 1 +Flags \Deleted'
```

But I then get the following response:

```
curl: (21) Quote command returned error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: STORE
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: +Flags
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \Deleted'
```

Comment: `curl --version`  ?

Comment: I've been trying on Window 10, version 7.55.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer, it seems like gmail is slightly different to every other example but found an example that works:

The following works:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/Inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X "STORE 1 +Flags \Deleted"
```

Followed by

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/Inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X "EXPUNGE"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether you should be using double quotes instead of single quotes?

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X 'UID STORE 1 +Flags \Deleted'
```

Should be:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X "UID STORE 1 +Flags \Deleted"
```

It looks like "STORE" etc. are being interpreted by curl as separate arguments that it's trying to treat as URLs.

Comment: I was but now I've put that in I get exactly the same response so that's a bit odd so unfortunately hasn't helped :(

Comment: It doesn't come up with any errors error now, although doesn't delete the email either

Comment: guess so thought the deleting would be the easy bit :(

Comment: Try putting `\r\n` on the end of the `-X` part and brackets round `\Deleted`.  I.e. `-X "UID STORE 1 +Flags (\Deleted)\r\n"`